# Bootstrap table export and HTML tags

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I'm attempting to use bootstrap table export to create a csv or pdf from a bootstrap table and I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

My data for the table contains some HTML to display a font awesome icon in place of text that I don't want to include in my export because this appears to be the reason for the error.

The data I'm currently loading into the table is:

```
data: [{
        status: statusIcon(1),
        vehicle: 'bd-one',
        time: '08:43',
        location: 'Main depot area',
        brief: '<i class="fa fa-info ba"></i>',
        driver: '<i class="fa fa-drivers-license driver"></i>'
    }, {
        status: statusIcon(2),
        vehicle: 'bd-two',
        time: '08:44',
        location: 'a515, ashbourne, de6',
        brief: '<i class="fa fa-info ba"></i>',
        driver: '<i class="fa fa-drivers-license driver"></i>'
    }],
```

Is there a way of maybe not including these columns in the export so that won't be throwing an error? Or is there a way of maybe escaping the HTML that still allows it to display in the table?

Comment: can you provide pen or fiddle?

Comment: what statusIcon function return?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with the bootstrap-table-export.js file - I had accidentally downloaded the html from github along with the js which was why it wasn't working - doh!